# How to reference and import reflect-metadata in Aurelia CLI project?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I want to integrate the reflect-metadata package from NPM into an Aurelia CLI project using TypeScript, but I can't find any guide on how to do this.

Is there a 'standard' way of integrating this polyfill, and how should it be used from within TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the existing Reflect polyfill that ships with Aurelia not enough? https://github.com/aurelia/polyfills/blob/master/src/reflect.js

If not, it's fairly simple to add `reflect-metadata` to an Aurelia CLI project.

1. `npm install --save reflect-metadata`
2. Add the `"reflect-metadata"` to the `dependencies` section of the `vendor-bundle` configuration in `aurelia.json`
3. Add `import "reflect-metadata";` to whatever TypeScript file where you need to use the API.

As far as using it in TypeScript, I'd check this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

I copied one of the examples from that page in to an Aurelia app and everything looked like it worked fine:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

export class App {
  message : string;

  constructor() {
    let greeter = new Greeter("Ashley");

    this.message = greeter.greet();
  }
}

const formatMetadataKey = Symbol("format");

function format(formatString: string) {
    return Reflect.metadata(formatMetadataKey, formatString);
}

function getFormat(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    return Reflect.getMetadata(formatMetadataKey, target, propertyKey);
}

class Greeter {
    @format("Hello, %s")
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        let formatString = getFormat(this, "greeting");
        return formatString.replace("%s", this.greeting);
    }
}
```

What it looked like when I ran it:

[image]

Comment: The Aurelia polyfill doesn't seem to provide typings for defineMetadata or getMetadata, I tried `import "aurelia-polyfills";` but it didn't work, the methods weren't defined. However, I've followed your guide and it seems to be working perfectly - I get typings for the full Reflect API and it works at runtime as expected, so thanks for that.

Comment: You might want to file an issue on the polyfills repo to request we create typings for the polyfills.